# Provisioning Vagrant with Chef role error

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, vagrantfile

I'm relatively new to Chef, and I'm trying to setup a Vagrant Box using Digital Ocean as a provider and Chef as a provisioner.  The issue seems to be with the roles, but as far as I can tell, they match up fine.  Thanks.

Here is my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|


  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest


  config.vm.provider :digital_ocean do |provider, override|
    config.vm.hostname = 'majestic-chaos-ubuntu14.04x64'
    override.ssh.private_key_path = '~/.ssh/id_rsa'
    override.vm.box = 'digital_ocean'
    provider.token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
    provider.image = 'Ubuntu 14.04 x64'
    provider.region = 'nyc2'
    provider.size = '512mb'
  end

  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = ['../../cookbooks']
    chef.roles_path = ['../../roles']
    chef.add_role ("majestic-chaos-ubuntu14.04x64")
  end
end
```

and my roles file:

```
name "majestic-chaos-ubuntu-14.04x64"

ssl_verify_mode :verify_peer

run_list(
  "recipe[apt]",
  "recipe[open-ssl]",
  "recipe[build-essential]",
  "recipe[chef-ruby_build]",
  "recipe[nodejs-cookbook]",
  "recipe[rbenv::user]",
  "recipe[rbenv::vagrant]",
  "recipe[zsh]",
  "recipe[vim]",
  "recipe[imagemagick]",
)

override_attributes(
  rbenv: {
    user_installs: [{
      user: 'vagrant',
      rubies: ["2.1.2"],
      global: "2.1.2",
      gems: {
        "2.1.2" => [
          { name: "bundler" }
        ]
      }
    }]
  }
)
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
[2014-09-18T16:05:48-04:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.16.2 ***
[2014-09-18T16:05:48-04:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 2934
[2014-09-18T16:05:51-04:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["role[majestic-chaos-
ubuntu14.04x64]"] from CLI options
default: [2014-09-18T16:05:51-04:00] ERROR: Role majestic-chaos-ubuntu14.04x64 (included 
by 'top level') is in the runlist but does not exist. Skipping expand.

[2014-09-18T16:05:51-04:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-   
stacktrace.out
[2014-09-18T16:05:51-04:00] ERROR: The expanded run list includes nonexistent roles: 
majestic-chaos-ubuntu14.04x64
[2014-09-18T16:05:51-04:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process 
exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Comment: change the ruby version in the Vagrant file !

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when launching a Vagrant image where the roles file was not being picked up. The solution I found for that was that for the `kitchen.yml` file the roles file should be in JSON format.  (The roles file listed above does not look like JSON).

As documented here: https://docs.chef.io/config_yml_kitchen.html

> `roles_path`  The relative path to the directory in which role data is located. **This data must be defined as JSON.**

Here are a few ruby commands to convert your `.rb` to JSON

```
require 'chef'
role = Chef::Role.new
role.from_file("./roles/useful_api_role.rb")
puts JSON.pretty_generate(role)
```

As a side effect, this above code will load up an rb config and you can validate that it's producing the role variables you expect.

Comment: Not the case with the `chef_solo` provisioner. This is true for `chef_zero` and things based on it though. The docs there are based on Chef's training materials, which only cover `chef_zero`.

Comment: Also this is talking about Vagrant, not Test Kitchen.

Answer (score -2):

Try using absolute paths for the roles and cookbooks:

```
chef.cookbooks_path = File.expand_path('../../cookbooks', __FILE__)
chef.roles_path = File.expand_path('../../roles', __FILE__)
```

Comment: Hey @estebanrules, any solution you found?  I am still facing this issue even after following this approach.

Comment: Why is this marked as correct, if the issue still exists and it did not solve your problem?

Comment: Yes I apologize, the answer should not have been marked correct.